# How can i deny continue the sub code lines after the try catch exception handling in public static void mvc property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, static, try-catch

I have an static class with some static void properties.

```
public static class Payment
{
   public static void ChargeTask(int paymentId)
        {
          //some code
           try
            {
               //some code
            }
           catch
            {
              //handle the exceptions. 
             how can i exit in this property
            }
          //deny continue this codes
        }
}
```

How can i deny continue the sub code lines after the try catch exception handling?

Comment: use `return;`, that's a method, by the way, not a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `return` keyword like this:

```
public static class Payment
{
   public static void ChargeTask(int paymentId)
        {
          //some code
           try
            {
               //some code
            }
           catch
            {
              //handle the exceptions. 
              return;
            }
          //deny continue this codes
        }
}
```